# Backbone RESTful JSON schema

Tags: json, rest, backbone.js

If I want to present the following data to a backbone.js collection, what should the JSON that I create look like?:

```
id: 1
fname: "John"
surname: "Lennon"
email: "john@beatles.com"
age: 22

id: 2
fname: "Paul"
surname: "McCartney"
email: "paul@beatles.com"
age: 22

id: 3
fname: "George"
surname: "Harrison"
email: "george@beatles.com"
age: 20

id: 4
fname: "Ringo"
surname: "Starr"
email: "ringo@beatles.com"
age: 24
```

I have been exporting it as follows:

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "fname":"John",
    "surname":"Lennon",
    "email":"john@beatles.com",
    "age":22
},{
    "id":2,
    "fname":"Paul",
    "surname":"McCartney",
    "email":"paul@beatles.com",
    "age":22
},{
    "id":3,
    "fname":"George",
    "surname":"Harrison",
    "email":"george@beatles.com",
    "age":20
},{
    "id":4,
    "fname":"Ringo",
    "surname":"Starr",
    "email":"ringo@beatles.com",
    "age":24
}]
```

When presented with the JSON above, my collection only seems to contain the final Beatle (Ringo).

---

**This is my View:**

```
var app = app || {};

app.BeatleView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '#page',

        template: Handlebars.getTemplate( 'account_statement' ),

        initialize: function() {
                console.info('init:',this.collection);
                this.render();
                this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
                this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
                this.collection.fetch();
        },

        // render library by rendering each book in its collection
        render: function() {
                var data = this.collection.toJSON();
        console.log('col', this.collection );  // added
                this.$el.html( this.template( {beatles: data} ));
                return this;
        }
});
```

**This is my Collection**

```
var app = app || {};

app.BeatlesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: app.Beatle,
        url: 'http://localhost/path/to/beatles',

        initialize: function() {
                console.log('Init Collection');
        }
});
```

**This is my Model**

```
var app = app || {};

// create a model to represent a single transaction on a statement
app.Transaction = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

**This is what a `console.log('col', this.collection );` in my view's render method show:**

```
col child {length: 1, models: Array[1], _byId: Object, _listenerId: "l2", _events: Object…}
_byId: Object
_events: Object
_listenerId: "l2"
length: 1
models: Array[1]
0: child
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
amount: 205.99
currency: "USD"
date: "2013-05-13"
id: 13
vendor: "Reebok Outlet"
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c3"
collection: child
id: 13
__proto__: Surrogate
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Surrogate
```

**My Handlebars Template looks like this:**

```
<h1>Your Statement</h1>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#each beatle}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{this.fname}} {{this.surname}}</td>
            <td>{{this.email}}</td>
            <td>{{this.age}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How are you loading the collection?

Comment: I have added more info -- hope it is what you wanted

Comment: I've never used Handlebars or Backbone, however are you sure that the template function expects JSON? Shouldn't be more something like `this.$el.html( this.template( {beatles: this.collection.models} ));` ? You can check how many records your collection contains by looking up it's `length` property.

Comment: add your handlebars snippet. The rest looks OK to me.

Comment: the problem looks like it's in the template

Comment: Also, the template works. I am just getting a single record displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the JSON I posted above was correct.

The problem was that the JSON I posted was pseudo-code and the JSON that I was actually outputting from my backend system was wrong -- all of the IDs in my output were the same number (copy/paste problem).

For anyone looking to create a Backbone / Handlebars app, the code above seems to be a good starting point.